# SELECT FROM two different tables with the same WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have two different tables. `cities_buildings` and `map_buildings`. Both have the EXACT **SAME** COLUMN names/structure.

Is it possible to do something like so, and still have each record from either table by themselves?

```
SELECT  cb.city_id,
    cb.type,cb.x,
    cb.y,
    mb.city_id,
    mb.type,
    mb.x,
    mb.y
FROM    cities_buildings AS cb,
    map_buildings AS mb
WHERE city_id IN (1,2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give us an example of what your desired output would be? I think I have a good guess of what you want to accomplish, but since I do not read minds I can not be sure. :-)

Comment: @anders Hi, I'm trying to join the results from the two tables by themselves. However, I do not have a 1:1 ratio of `cb` and `mb` records, causing there to be two records on one row like so: http://puu.sh/j2Lxy/e0d8233299.png --- is there any way to put all the records on their own line without running two separate SELECT queries?

Comment: Thanks. Unless one of the answers hasn't already solved the problem, it would be great if you could provide us with a picture (or text table) of your desired output. Also, could you please update your question with any new information and not just post it in comments? Comments are the second class citizens of SO and someone passing by later should be able to get all the vital info from just the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want to accomplish, but perhaps this will do it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT city_id, type, x, y FROM cities_buildings
    UNION ALL
    SELECT city_id, type, x, y FROM map_buildings
) WHERE city_id IN (1,2)
```

This concatenats the tables, and then finds rows with a `city_id` of either 1 or 2 from either one of them.

If you have duplicates in the tables and don't want duplicates in the output, use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. That will have an performance impact, though.

If you want to be able to track what table a row came from, you can change the inner part of the query to this:

```
SELECT city_id, type, x, y, 'cities_buildings' AS table_name FROM cities_buildings
UNION ALL
SELECT city_id, type, x, y, 'map_buildings' AS table_name FROM map_buildings
```

If you follow this approach using `UNION` (without `ALL`) would be pointless since there will be no common rows between the tables.

Comment: Perfect, answered everything including how I could tell which record was from which table. :)

Comment: Glad it helped. (Added a small note on `UNION ALL` at the end.)

Comment: Oops, quick question. MySQL doesn't seem to like the second query you provided. It spits this out: `... for the right syntax to use near 'AS mb FROM map_buildings ) WHERE city_id IN (1,2)'` - Doesn't seem to like defining columns. Could it be my version? My MySQL version is `5.5.27`

Comment: There is a missing comma after the y (will update answer to correct). Do you have it in your code as well? Also, I think the column names must be exactly the same in both `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Silly me, I can't believe I didn't see that. I really appreciate the help! Works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
SELECT  cb.city_id,
cb.type,cb.x,
cb.y,
mb.city_id,
mb.type,
mb.x,
mb.y
FROM    cities_buildings AS cb,
map_buildings AS mb
WHERE mb.city_id IN (1,2) AND cb.city_id IN (1,2);
```

however this is probably better:

```
SELECT  cb.city_id,
cb.type,cb.x,
cb.y,
mb.city_id,
mb.type,
mb.x,
mb.y
FROM    cities_buildings AS cb,
map_buildings AS mb
WHERE mb.city_id IN (1,2) AND mb.city=cb.city;
```

This relates the cities.

Alternative (and most used is):

```
SELECT  cb.city_id,
cb.type,cb.x,
cb.y,
mb.city_id,
mb.type,
mb.x,
mb.y
FROM    cities_buildings AS cb
LEFT JOIN map_buildings AS mb ON mb.city=cb.city
WHERE mb.city_id IN (1,2);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! This is almost what I want to happen. But is it possible to split the results from each table? e.g.: this is what it looks like when I run your query: http://puu.sh/j2KZN/29c317d62b.png --- this happens when there isn't a perfect 1:1 ratio of `cb` buildings to `mb` buildings.

Comment: Ah, not a perfect ratio: Then we use LEFT JOIN assuming that table CB always has more then table mb: See updated query